# If I want to prove something for finite dimensional real vector space, would it be enough to prove it for $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, if I want to show that any $n$-dimensional real vector space is not a countable union of its proper subspaces.

Note that for $V_i$ to be a subspace of $V$, there exists a linear transformation $T: V \to V$ of rank $<n$, such that $T(V)= V_i$. By Sard's theorem the image of $V$ has measure zero. Then I reach a contradiction by applying the subadditivity property of Lebesgue measure if I assume that there exists $V= \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}V_i$ where $V_i$ is a proper subspace of $V$. $$\mu(V)=\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} V_i\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(V_i)=0.$$

However, my argument probably only works for $\mathbb{R}^n$ as I only know the Sard's theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Would it be enough to say that any $n$-dimensional real vector space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ to make it sound?

Comment: Almost every property is preserved by isomorphism. To be sure, just verify whether that's the case. The property you mentioned is definitely preserved by isomorphism.